# Is there any way I can download OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B on a Windows laptop?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

So, I am trying to install OpenCV with Python 3 onto my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. The problem is, the commands are in Linux, and I need to install it using Windows. Is there any way I can install it using windows, or is it absolutely necessary to use Linux?

The link to the Linux commands:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/27/installing-opencv-3-0-for-both-python-2-7-and-python-3-on-your-raspberry-pi-2/

Comment: Can we just clarify - you are trying to install OpenCV on a Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspbian??), but are downloading the install files on a windows laptop? Or are you trying to install it on your Windows laptop?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to install OpenCV on a Raspberry Pi 3, which is running Raspbian, but I need to use a Windows computer rather than a Linux computer. Hopefully that clarified the question

Comment: Secure shell i.e. ssh is a common method for controlling one computer remotely from another. PuTTy is a popular ssh client for windows. (that's why bot the answers provided mention it) Once you have it installed on your windows machine you should be able to use the the IP from your PI to open a connection that will let you type bash commands (or as you call them commands in linux) to your rasberry pi from within your windows environment. The pi is running linux so if you want to manipulate it you must comply with the rules of linux.

Comment: @KevinKarnani Yes, that clarifies things, thanks. Like everyone else has said, you will need to connect to the Raspberry Pi using PuTTY if you want to run the Pi without a monitor. However, as Ellery pointed out, you will need to enable SSH on the Pi before you can do this. So it might just be simplest to plug it into a monitor/TV and run commands on the Pi directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be to connect your Raspberry Pi to a monitor or TV via HDMI, plug in a keyboard/mouse on USB, and then execute the commands directly on the Pi which is running Linux (ether NOOBS or Raspbian OSs depending on what's on your SD card).

You will need to use the Raspi-Config tool on the terminal on the Pi to enable SSH access, which in term will allow you to connect to your Pi from Windows via [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your Raspberry Pi should be running Linux, which means that you do need to run the Linux commands.

From a Windows computer, you can remotely access and run commands on your Raspberry Pi through a program such as PuTTy. There's a lot of tutorials on the topic available on the internet.

Let us know if you need help with a specific step.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a keyboard and monitor for your pi Use putty to ssh to to it over the network. Once logged in to the shell use the commands provided on this link to install open cv and python. http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/